# AlarmManager killing scheduled alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I want to make a daily notification but my app is getting killed in alarmManager

code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (60 * 1000 * 5),
                alarmIntent);
    } 
}
```

I have been watching the alarmManager contents using adb command `"adb shell dumpsys alarm > dump.txt"`

Its there when it starts but when my phone goes to deep sleep the scheduled alarm disappears.

When I lower the value to 1 minute, the intent triggers but with a longer time the alarm disappears.

I'm guessing this has something to do with battery optimizations on deep sleep?

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

What I have ultimately done is use this library: https://github.com/evernote/android-job which handles everything for me.

I have [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) installed and removed my app from the list to be greenified and it seems to solve the problem.